# Is there a pattern in figures whose perimeter is the same as their area?

Tags: pattern-recognition, polygons

Here's what I've found so far.

- Circumference of a circle with identical circumference and area: $4\pi$
- Side length of a triangle with identical perimeter and area: $4\sqrt{3}$

And so on...

- Square: $4$
- Pentagon: $4\sqrt{5 - 2\sqrt{5}}$
- Hexagon: $\frac{4\sqrt{3}}{3}$
- Heptagon: $\frac{4\cos{\frac{3\pi}{14}}}{1 + \sin{\frac{3\pi}{14}}}$
- Octagon: $4(1+ \sqrt{2})$

Is there a pattern here with the 4s?

Comment: Every real is four times something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can look at a regular $n$-gon of "radius" $r$, i.e., the convex hull of $r$ times the $n$-th roots of unity.

Connecting the vertices of the polygon to the origin gives you $n$ isosceles triangles of area $\frac{r^2}{2}\sin \frac{2\pi}{n}$. The total area of the $n$-gon is thus

$$A = \frac{nr^2}{2} \sin \frac{2\pi}{n}.$$

To calculate the length $l$ of the third side of these triangles, we can bisect the side to get two right triangles, and then

$$l = 2r\sin \frac{\pi}{n}$$
and the total perimeter is
$$P = 2r n \sin \frac{\pi}{n}.$$

Now we can solve for $r$:
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{nr^2}{2}\sin\frac{2\pi}{n} &= 2rn\sin \frac{\pi}{n}\\
r \sin \frac{2\pi}{n} &= 4\sin \frac{\pi}{n}\\
2r \sin \frac{\pi}{n} \cos \frac{\pi}{n} &= 4\sin \frac{\pi}{n}\\
r &= 2\sec \frac{\pi}{n}.
\end{align*}$$

Plugging this radius into the formula for perimeter gives you
$$P = 4n\tan \frac{\pi}{n}$$
and as you observed, this formula has a natural factor of 4 in it. And indeed,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} 4n\tan\frac{\pi}{n} = 4\pi.$$

Comment: Beautiful answer!

Comment: But why is the minimum reached at the heptagon?

Comment: @LeeSleek Why do you think that the heptagon is a minimum? The perimeter decreases monotonically as the number of sides increases, with the circle being the minimum: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Plot[4+n+Tan[Pi%2Fn]%2C+{n%2C4%2C100}]

Comment: @LeeSleek I think there is an error i your octagon calculation: I get $4(\sqrt{2}-1).$

Comment: Ah, yes. My mistake.